# Where is the configuration file?

Tags: mysql, windows-xp

I have just installed MySQL on my Windows XP machine.

Now, because of the nature of my task I need to make some changes to the `my.ini` file.

However all I can see in the `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` is the file `my-default.ini`.

What should I do?

My intent is to rename this file to `my.ini` and make the changes or copy and rename it to some other place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a copy of the default, name it `my.ini` and then restart MySQL.

Per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-file-location.html):

> The new MySQL Configuration Wizard places the `my.ini` file in the
>   installation directory of the MySQL server. This helps associate
>   configuration files with particular server instances.
>
> To ensure that the MySQL server knows where to look for the `my.ini`
>   file, an argument similar to this is passed to the MySQL server as
>   part of the service installation:

```
--defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\my.ini"
```

> Here, `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1` is replaced with the
>   installation path to the MySQL Server. The `--defaults-file` option
>   instructs the MySQL server to read the specified file for
>   configuration options when it starts.